Stability of multistep methods that contain second derivative
Consider the numerical method $y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\frac{h}{2}[\frac{dy_{n}}{dt}+\frac{dy_{n+1}}{dt}]+\frac{h^{2}}{12}[\frac{d^{2}y_{n}}{dt^{2}}-\frac{d^{2}y_{n+1}}{dt^{2}}]$ where $\frac{d}{dt}$ is the derivative symbol for solving $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y)$ and $y(t_{0})=y_{0}$, $\frac{dy_{n}}{dt}=f(t_{n},y_{n})$. Find the region of absolute stability and argue that it contains the entire negative real axis.
I tried to write $\frac{dy}{dt}=\lambda y$ and tried to write characteristic equation in terms of the power of a variable $r$ and $|r(\lambda\Delta t) |<1$ for all the roots r will be desired region for characteristic equation but the reason I could not make a good progress is the second derivative. I do not know how to write
the characteristic equation exactly in this case
